# MVC Error Message Hyperlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, error-handling

I am using a partial view for error messages.

```
<div class="@(Html.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid ? "validation-summary-valid" : "validation-summary-errors") panel panel-danger"
 data-valmsg-summary="true">
<div class="errorMessage">
    <ul class="blts">
        @foreach(var modelError in Model.SelectMany(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Value.Errors))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(modelError.ErrorMessage))
            {
                <li>@modelError.ErrorMessage</li>
            }
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

In the view, I am simple calling

```
 @Html.Partial("ValidationSummary", ViewData.ModelState)
```

Can someone tell me if its possible to hyperlink the error message to its correspondent field with error?
In Html, I used to do it like this but I am not being able to figure out a possible way for doing it in MVC4?
I have possible 12 required fields which cannot be left empty and if filled, should be text only. So, there are lot of scenarios for errors for which I am showing the error summary.

```
 <div id="validationerror">
 <h2 id="errorsummary">2 errors were found in your registration.</h2>
 <ul>
 <li id="error1">
 <a href="#name" onclick="setfocus('name')">
 The Name field can not be empty.
 Please enter your name.</a></li>
 <li id="error2">
 <a href="#age" onclick="setfocus('age')">
 The Age field can not be empty.
 Please enter your age</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```